# Battery charge time

Tags: battery-charging

Is there an existing formula one can use to calculate charging time of a battery?

I have a 12V 100Ah gel battery with a 30A charge controller.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you post the link to the charge controller? Strait calculation is 100Ah / 30A = 3.3 (h). But, that is without knowing what the charger really does.

Answer (score 6):

Sort of, but not really.

If you assume the battery is discharged to the limit (but not damaged,) then the charge time is simply the capacity divided by the charge rate.  In your case, 100Ah/30A = 3.33 hours.

In reality, the battery may not be completely discharged so it may reach the full state faster.  It might not take a charge at the full 30A, and so charge slower than calculated.

Batteries aren't like buckets you can dump electricity into. They are complicated beasts that accept and deliver current at different rates depending on all kinds of reactions between the materials they are made of and the available voltage and current from the charger.